# Different characters for some keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm running Ubuntu in virtual machine and what I've noticed is that the shortcuts to characters (like : ; ") are different than shortcuts used in windows. I'm guessing this has to do with OS (or is this just a VMWare thing?) so my question is if it's possible to remap them so I could be using the same shortcuts in Windows and Linux?

Comment: What are shortcuts? You mean you don't have those characters on your keyboard and need some keycombination to generate them?

Comment: Well for example when I press Shift+2 in windows it prints out " . If I use the same combination in I get @. What I would like is to get " (and other characters as mentioned in first post) printed in Linux with the same combination as in Windows.

Comment: That is not a short-cut, that is the long way around, there is no short cut to typing. A keyboard-short-cut, is a key combination that circumvents a load of tedious mouse clicking.

Comment: Why the downvote, this is a good question, but the terminology is all mixed up (however remap is exactly the correct word for what they need to do).

Comment: @richard Probably somebody thought this should've been asked over at AskUbuntu in the first place; this is surely debatable. Best ignore the quick downvotes of some triggerhappy members (and I'm guilty of that myself in one case or two), begging for upvotes doesn't make it better :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have set the wrong keyboard layout. See here to get started:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/459617/keyboard-layout-isnt-kept-upon-reboot
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/471849/change-keyboard-layout-permanently-in-xubuntu-14-04

Comment: It is not an OS issue, you have just got US keyboard layout set. MS-Windows dose the same, if you do not ask for something different.

Comment: @richard The links were meant to give the OP a starting point, not for addressing his actual issue, though I didn't state so explicitely. They were just the first search results that seem to match closely enough, and both describe several ways to check and set the layout.